# Do these polynomials have a name? Ideal generated by coefficients is the whole ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, terminology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and consider $f(x)=a_0+\cdots+a_nx^n\in R[x]$ such that the generated ideal $\langle a_0,\dots,a_n\rangle=R$. Does this polynomial have a name?

Comment: You’ll want to look at the notion of “content of a polynomial”.

Comment: Isn't that only for polynomials with integer coefficients? @AviSteiner

Comment: it’s defined in general to be the ideal generated by the coefficients